# Как правильно определить тип и вывести ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = True
while a==True:
    answer = int(input())
    if isinstance(answer, int):
        print(answer**5)
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Как вывести ошибку, если в `input` тип = `str`?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` всегда возвращает строку, поэтому можно только отловить исключение при попытке преобразования строки в число:

```
while True:
    answer = input()
    try: 
        answer = int(answer)
        print(answer**5)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error')
```

P.S. Для организации бесконечного цикла достаточно написать `while True:`

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev:  в общем случае, `print(answer**5)` выражение должны быть вне `try/except`. Только `int(..)` должно быть внутри `try/except ValueError`.